# How to redirect finished form php based on country

Tags: php, forms

I want to redirect my form page after submitting form based on visitor's country. How i can set the page that the user is redirected to?

Here is my sample code:

```
if ($lang['COUNTRY'] =="United States")  <form action="US_Finish.php?&sessionid=<?php echo generateRandomString(115); ?>&securessl=true" method="post" name="us" id="us" class="proceed"> 
if ($lang['COUNTRY'] =="Australia")  <form action="AU_Finish.php?&sessionid=<?php echo generateRandomString(115); ?>&securessl=true" method="post" name="au" id="au" class="proceed">
```

Comment: Aside from the obvious formatting issues in your code sample, what is wrong with your current approach? Would not be my approach, but I don't see what that would not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, you don't have to say thank you at the end of your question or say it's urgent. Just ask your question, describe it as good as you can and somebody will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, your code isn't correct as you're mixing PHP and HTML without delimiters.

To answer your question, I'd use a `switch` statement to set a variable with the required destination, like this:

```
switch ($lang['COUNTRY']) {
   case 'United States':
       $destination = 'US_Finish.php';
       break;
   // etc. as required
    default:
        $destination = 'some_other_page.php';
}

print '<form action="' . $destination . '" // ... (etc) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of your code is not right. It should be like this, if you were to use it:

```
if ($lang['COUNTRY'] =="United States")  echo '<form action="US_Finish.php?&sessionid='.generateRandomString(115).'&securessl=true" method="post" name="us" id="us" class="proceed"><button type="submit">Submit form</button></form>';
if ($lang['COUNTRY'] =="Australia")  echo '<form action="AU_Finish.php?&sessionid='.generateRandomString(115).'&securessl=true" method="post" name="au" id="au" class="proceed"><button type="submit">Submit form</button></form>';
```

But that might have been for example purposes...
This is another way to do it:

```
$countries = [
    "Australia"=>"AU",
    "United States"=>"US"
];

$countryCode = $countries[$lang['COUNTRY']];

$form = '<form action="'.$countryCode.'_Finish.php?&sessionid='.generateRandomString(115).'&securessl=true" method="post" name="'.strtolower($countryCode).'" id="'.strtolower($countryCode).'" class="proceed"><button type="submit">Submit form</button></form>';
echo $form;
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your language as button value and every submit button should have same name then in controller ( where you post form data) you will be able to redirect specific language by the value of button value

```
<?php if ($lang['COUNTRY'] =="United States"){ ?>
<form action="US_Finish.php?&sessionid=<?php echo generateRandomString(115); ?>&securessl=true" method="post" name="us" id="us" class="proceed">
 <button name="button" value="us" >Submit</button>  
</form>
<?php } else if($lang['COUNTRY'] =="Australia"){ ?>
  <form action="AU_Finish.php?&sessionid=<?php echo generateRandomString(115); ?>&securessl=true" method="post" name="au" id="au" class="proceed">
  <button name="button" value="au" >Submit</button> 
  </form>
<?php } ?>
```

And in where you post get posted data and redirect page as `$_POST['button']` value.

```
<?php

if($_POST){
   if($_POST['button'] =='us'){
   // save posted info here

    redirect('us_page');

   }else if($_POST['button'] =='au'){
   // save posted info here

    redirect('au_page');

   }
}
```